# Delphi mock and databases

Tags: database, delphi, mocking

I was reading Nick Hodges' blog http://nickhodges.com/post/Delphi-Mocks-The-Basics.aspx which is very interesting.

However it doesn't say how I can test classes with statements referring to databases in it for instance `TQuery.Next or TQuery.ExecSQL or TQuery.FieldByName...` etc

Did anybody face the same issue ? If so how did you solve it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to say what you are asking. The article you point is part of a lengthier series, and the reason you may be having problems seeing it is that, in order to make your code testable, you probably need to refactor your code first to make use of some common patterns that are fit for automated testing. In the case of TQuery, for example, you may need to use methods that receive such TQuery object as a parameter, and the TQuery object may need to be an interface instead of an object. That's only a couple of guesses.

Comment: @leonardo "you may need to use methods that receive such TQuery object as a parameter, and the TQuery object may need to be an interface instead of an object" do you mean I have to put the TQuery in an interface ?

Comment: Yes. Is is better to think about it the other way around - design from the start using interfaces. This way a TQuery-based class will just be a specific implementation for the interface. [This article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/10/14/Interfaces-in-practice%3A-dependency-injection,-stubs-and-mocks) may be of help, although it is specific to the mORMot framework.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link above, it was very informative. Are you aware of any example that starts from a traditional approach and goes to the interface implementation so that I can see the transition from one method to the other ? Maybe I am asking too much.

Again, many thanks for providing this link.

Answer (score 2):

What we have done at work is to have repositories that return a TDataSet. This way, you create a mock/fake of the repository (depending if you want to test how many tests methods get called, etc). Example:

```
TMyDatabaseRepository =  class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDatabaseRepository)
  // .. blah ..
  function GetAllTheFun : TDataSet;
  // .. blah ..
end;

TMyProcessThatAccessesTheDatabase = class
  // .. blah ..
public
  constructor Create(const AMyDatabaseRepository : IMyDatabaseRepository);    
  // .. blah ..
end;
```

So when it comes to testing, we passing in a mock `IMyDatabaseRepository`. `GetAllTheFun` actually returns a [TKbmMemTable](http://www.components4programmers.com/products/kbmmemtable/) with data sample data set up.

While I haven't used [Delphi Mocks](http://www.finalbuilder.com/Resources/Blogs/PostId/417/Introducing-Delphi-Mocks.aspx), I do remember that you can override methods on the 'fly' (or something like that), so you might not need to go through the trouble of creating a separate class that implements `IMyDatabaseRepository`

Edit:
That is a fair large subject to try and cover here but there a few number of web sites (blogs) that cover this type of thing:

- http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/pimp-your-unit-tests-using-mock-objects.html
- http://www.finalbuilder.com/Resources/Blogs/PostId/417/introducing-delphi-mocks.aspx
- http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/10/14/Stubs-and-Mocks-for-Delphi-with-mORMot
- [http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/10/14/Interfaces-in-practice%3A-dependency-injection%2C-stubs-and-mocks](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/10/14/Interfaces-in-practice%3a-dependency-injection,-stubs-and-mocks)
- http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/10/14/Advanced-mocks-and-stubs

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for your answer.
As I am not familiar with this topic, can you please explain more in details how the whole process works ?
Many thanks

Comment: I have edit my answer with some links that may be useful, as the topic is a fairly large one.